# как получить значения с mustache и обработать их при помощи JDBC?

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, mustache

```
 @PostMapping("/")
   public String createTodo(@RequestParam Integer ID,@RequestParam String NAME, Map<String, Object> model) {
       Todo todo =new Todo();
       todo.setId(ID);
       todo.setName(NAME);
       System.out.println(ID);
       System.out.println(NAME);
       todoRepository.createTodo(NAME,ID);

       return "/";
   }
```

CODE Model

```
   private Integer id;
   private String name;

   public Todo() {
   }

   public Todo(Integer id, String name) {
       this.id = id;
       this.name = name;
   }

   public Integer getId() {
       return id;
   }

   public void setId(Integer id) {
       this.id = id;
   }

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }

}
```

Code save method jdbc

```
 public int createTodo(String name,Integer id) {
       return jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO \"TODO\" (\"NAME\",\"ID\") VALUES(?,?)", name, id);
   }
```

Не понимаю почему в дебагере и в логе пусто как будто с jdbc не получает с фронта либо теряет данные.
код фронта

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
Main
<form>
    <label>
        <input name="ID" tag="ID" placeholder="Id"/>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input name="NAME" tag="NAME" placeholder="NAME"/>
    </label>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

{{#task}}
    <tr>
   <td>{{ID}}</td>
        <td>{{NAME}}</td>
    </tr>
{{/task}}


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Нужно установить получаемый метод со стороны клиента.
В данном случае метод Post.

Comment: постарайтесь давать чуть более развернутые ответы